# An optimization problem involving matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization

This is a problem derived from [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586178/rank-of-a-matrix-in-specific-form), and first thanks to everyone who replies in that answer.

Consider $n\in N_+$ and a vector of length $m$: $a=[a_1,...,a_m]^T$, where $a_i\neq a_j, \forall 1\leq i<j\leq m$, and assume $m>n$. And consider the matrix $A\in R^{m\times m}$ and $[A]_{ij}=(a_i−a_j)^n$. My simulation implies that the rank of $A$ is $n+1$. In [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586178/rank-of-a-matrix-in-specific-form) there is a proof verifying that the rank of $A$ is at most $n+1$. But the guess that the rank equals $n+1$ requires further verification.

Another simulation result is that when $n=2$, $A$ seems to be semi-definite, but I still cannot give a proof.

Finally, I am considering an optimization problem for $n=2$ as follows:
$$
\max_x x^TAx, s.t. 1^Tx=1, x\geq 0
$$
where $A$ is given and $x\in R^m$ and $1$ is a $m$-length vector of ones. I wonder whether there is an analytic result for the optimization problem.